# Display USB webcam video to composite output

Tags: webcam, composite-video

I have an old TV that has a composite video connection (analog video) and a USB webcam. I would like to stream videos from the usb webcam on the old TV. I connected and could see kind of booting list on the TV when Raspberry Pi starts, but I could not see any videos from the USB webcam. I also noticed that a LED light on the usb webcam becomes off and TV provides black screen.

When I use HDMI display and Python for webcam display, it successfully works. But when I use a composite output by commenting `hdmi_force_hotplug=1`, the usb webcam does not work.

Can you help me to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe have a read here and use [this package instead](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=7557) of the python script. But to answer you question, yes the Webcam can be streamed via composite. You just need the right script, if you post me your script I can try and figure out your problem.